Collecting bot.UserId and checking in a given excel file
I am currently running into the following problem:
I have my PowerAutomate Skill which takes the Variable AzureID. This AzureID Variable is getting its value from the Copilot Studio as the pre-set variable "bot.UserId". Now I am passing this variable in the same PowerAutomate Skill into my Get Row Connector to check if the AzureID is currently present in this Excel file. The file is linked correctly but I am running into the error 2001 "Bot content is invalid".
Any advice?
I am really running out of ideas.
Thanks!
Image1
Image2
I tried so much stuff from the Microsoft forum and I only find 2 topics which were not helpful at all for me.
EDIT: When I run the flow manually with a given AzureID is runs successfully. However if I run it from the copilot it doesn't even start.
